# Edit "order pay" endpoint content on Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to disable the email input step on the order pay page.

I intend to send the order pay link to the customer via email directly after the order is created, and I don't want them to need to reenter their email again.

I tried the CheckoutWC plugin thet redesigned the order pay page, but the email input still has the default theme design (and I'd like to remove this step completely).